# How to take difference of values on t and t-1 using only the ids that exist on both days in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How should I write python logic to calculate difference of Value between t and t-1 only if id on t exist on t-1 too? In other words, if an id is on t-1 but disappears on t, it is excluded from the calculation and exluded from output dataframe. Thank you!

Example:

| Date | id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2024 | a | 100 |
| 1/2/2024 | a | 101 |
| 1/1/2024 | b | 99 |
| 1/5/2024 | b | 97 |
| 1/6/2024 | b | 98 |
| 1/2/2024 | c | 98 |
| 1/5/2024 | c | 97 |
| 1/5/2024 | a | 97 |

Desired output:

| Date | id | Value | Delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2024 | a | 100 |  |
| 1/2/2024 | a | 101 | 1 |
| 1/5/2024 | b | 97 |  |
| 1/6/2024 | b | 98 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

df = df.sort_values(by="Date")

df = (
    df.groupby("id")
    .apply(
        lambda x: x[(mask := x["Date"].diff().eq("1 day")) | mask.shift(-1)],
        include_groups=False,
    )
    .droplevel(1)
    .reset_index()
)

df["Delta"] = df.groupby("id")["Value"].diff()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  id       Date  Value  Delta
0  a 2024-01-01    100    NaN
1  a 2024-01-02    101    1.0
2  b 2024-01-05     97    NaN
3  b 2024-01-06     98    1.0
```

Comment: thank you! Slightly updated a bit: `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])<br/>
df = df.sort_values(by="Date")<br/>

df = (
    df.groupby("id")
    .apply(
        lambda x: x[(mask := x["Date"].diff().eq(pd.Timedelta(days=1))) | mask.shift(-1)]
    )
    .droplevel(1)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)<br/>

df["Delta"] = df.groupby("id")["Value"].diff()`